# Ruby:copy two rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, row

I am a newcomer in Ruby.
I have a sample (input text) like:

```
Message:
update attributes in file and commit version
----
Modified
```

I need to put in line the row after "message" tag. Note that this row can be and close with "message" like

```
Message:update attributes in file and commit version
```

I've tried like this:

```
if line =~/Message/
```

But of course it doesn't search the next row.

Can anyone help me how to catch rows between tags "Message" and "---"
If you know some examples please type a link

Update: the whole code

```
require 'csv'
data = []
File.foreach("new7.txt") do |line|
  line.chomp!
  if line =~ /Revision/
    data.push [line]
  elsif line =~ /Author/
    if data.last and not data.last[1]
      data.last[1] = line
    else
      data.push [nil, line]
    end
  elsif line=~/^Message:(.*)^-/m 
    if data.last and not data.last[2]
      data.last[2] = line
    else
      data.push [nil, nil, line]
    end
  end
end

CSV.open('new1.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  data.each do |record|
    csv << record
  end
    enter code here
```

Input file:

```
Revision: 37407
Author: imakarov
Date: 21 июня 2013 г. 10:23:28
Message:my infomation
dmitry name
```

Output csv file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/^Message:(.*)^---/m` as your regex.  The `/m` allows you to match across line boundaries.  See http://rubular.com/r/FhqiKx0XyI

Update #1: Here's sample output from irb:

```
Peters-MacBook-Air-2:bot palfvin$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > line = "\nMessage:first-line\nsecond-line\n---\nthird-line"
 => "\nMessage:first-line\nsecond-line\n---\nthird-line" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > line =~ /^Message:(.*)^-/m
 => 1 
1.9.3p194 :003 > $1
 => "first-line\nsecond-line\n" 
1.9.3p194 :004 >
```

Comment: I just checked and other similar questions have been asked/answered on SO. Did you search first? I'm wondering if we should mark this as duplicate or if there was something that kept you from finding it.

Comment: @PeterAlfin thank you a lot! But is it correct if I use this expression like this: if line=~/^Message:(.*)^-/ Unfortunetely it doesn't work

Comment: No, you need `m` at the end of the regex (following the trailing slash). That's the key enabler.

Comment: @PeterAlfin I've tried to write like this:
if line=~/^Message:(.*)^-/m
but it's not correct. How will be correct with "/m" ?

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Can you show me the surrounding code and full output? See update to answer for an example of what I'm seeing.

Comment: The problem is that you're only getting one line into the `line` variable each time through the `foreach` loop. The solution I gave you only works when the string you are matching to contains multiple lines.